# Can't connect mongo shell to Atlas cluster

Tags: mongodb

There is some issue coming while connect mongo shell to the atlas cluster. It is saying that No primary detected for set Cluster0-shard-0.

```
ashish@ashish-Not-Specified:~$ mongo "mongodb://cluster0-shard-00-00-pth8i.mongodb.net:27017,cluster0-shard-00-01-pth8i.mongodb.net:27017,cluster0-shard-00-02-pth8i.mongodb.net:27017/test?replicaSet=Cluster0-shard-0" --authenticationDatabase admin --ssl --username m001-student --password m001-mongodb-basics
    MongoDB shell version: 3.2.17
    connecting to: mongodb://cluster0-shard-00-00-pth8i.mongodb.net:27017,cluster0-shard-00-01-pth8i.mongodb.net:27017,cluster0-shard-00-02-pth8i.mongodb.net:27017/test?replicaSet=Cluster0-shard-0
    2017-10-25T22:12:00.759+0530 I NETWORK  [thread1] Starting new replica set monitor for Cluster0-shard-0/cluster0-shard-00-00-pth8i.mongodb.net:27017,cluster0-shard-00-01-pth8i.mongodb.net:27017,cluster0-shard-00-02-pth8i.mongodb.net:27017
    2017-10-25T22:12:00.759+0530 I NETWORK  [ReplicaSetMonitorWatcher] starting
    2017-10-25T22:12:09.080+0530 W NETWORK  [thread1] No primary detected for set Cluster0-shard-0
    2017-10-25T22:12:18.389+0530 I NETWORK  [ReplicaSetMonitorWatcher] Socket recv() timeout  34.204.152.215:27017
    2017-10-25T22:12:18.610+0530 W NETWORK  [thread1] No primary detected for set Cluster0-shard-0
    2017-10-25T22:12:18.610+0530 E QUERY    [thread1] Error: connect failed to replica set Cluster0-shard-0/cluster0-shard-00-00-pth8i.mongodb.net:27017,cluster0-shard-00-01-pth8i.mongodb.net:27017,cluster0-shard-00-02-pth8i.mongodb.net:27017 :
    connect@src/mongo/shell/mongo.js:223:14
    @(connect):1:6

    exception: connect failed
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

@ashishkumar148, I would like to say that as per MongoDB BOL  [Here](https://docs.atlas.mongodb.com/) , MongoDB Atlas cluster only able to connect with **MongoDB 3.4 version**, due to Mongo Shell with TLS/SSL support.

I have gone through you mongo shell log , where i have found out that as you are using  **MongoDB shell version: 3.2.17**.

I am also attaching the Sandbox MongoDB Cluster connect screen shot to you.

[image]

**Note:-** Before making the connection with MongoDB Atlas with MongoDB shell, make sure that you have successfully configured your IP address through Mongo Atlas `IP whitelist` [Here](https://docs.atlas.mongodb.com/mongo-shell-connection/?_ga=2.261840525.1873437810.1508999880-1094601629.1504602550) .And the IP status is `Active`. And during the connection the User ID & Password should be used, which you have `Assigned` in `MongoDB Atlas cluster` creation time.

Answer (score 0):

It could not connect to the cluster nodes... Probably firewall was blocking access to port 27017, if the cluster was running.

Comment: Firewall is not blocking the 'port 27017'. Because the OP is able to run mongo shell.

Answer (score 0):

I currently have this challenge until I discovered that the problem was the difference between the mongo server version and the shell. I tried to connect the same mongo server with a mongo shell of the same version and it worked.

Comment: I'm not sure that this answers the question asked? Maybe if you want to flag it yourself as a comment - might be an idea? I know that you have to have a certain rep for comments.